# ServerAlias on OSX Mountain Lion webserver not resolving

Tags: macos, virtualhost, apache, httpd.conf

I have a problem with ServerAliases not resolving to the corresponding server.

My hosts file is set up as such (this is part of trying to set up APE so please excuse the extraneous code):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1 testy.local
127.0.0.1 testsite.local
127.0.0.1 ape-test.local
127.0.0.1 chickens.cluck.com
127.0.0.1 ape.ape-test.local
127.0.0.1 ape2.ape-test.local
```

And the httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ape-test.local
        ServerAlias ape.ape-test.local
        ServerAlias test.ape-test.local
        ServerAlias *.ape.ape-test.local

        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testy.local
    ServerAlias testy
    ServerAlias fish.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Sites/testsite"
    <Directory /Users/myusername/Sites/testsite/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual hosts have been enabled in httpd.conf, and testy.local resolves to the correct directory. But using 'testy/' or 'fish.local' will not resolve.

There appears to be nothing written to the error log or console either, and running `sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k start` reveals no errors.
Running `httpd -S` reveals no problems either:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ape-test.local (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost ape-test.local (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost testy.local (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:53)
Syntax OK
```

So it appears as just the ServerAlias isn't working.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your host file, it doesn't seem you provided 'testy' or 'fish.local' in your host file. You just need to enter both of these domains in your host file and you should be all set then.

You need to add them as I did below,

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1 fish.local
127.0.0.1 testy
127.0.0.1 testy.local
127.0.0.1 testsite.local
127.0.0.1 ape-test.local
127.0.0.1 chickens.cluck.com
127.0.0.1 ape.ape-test.local
127.0.0.1 ape2.ape-test.local
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @donnyB It's good to know you got it working. Did this solve your issue? If yes plz make my answer as the right answer:)

Comment: Thanks @humayun, a misunderstanding on my part. I was following the APE setup tutorial where they include the line _ServerAlias *.ape.yourdomain.com_. As the asterix operator doesn't have this functionality in the hosts file I thought this was a method of Aliasing many urls at once. I presume then that every url must be listed in the hosts file separately?

Comment: Yes, you can't have wildcard entry in host file that's why you need to add every entry separately or alternatively you could add like this,
127.0.0.1 fish.local testy testy.local testsite.local

Comment: Put another way, a requisite of using APE is that 'x.server.foo.com must resolve to the same IP as server.foo.com for any DNS-legal value of x'. Is the only way to do this on Mountain Lion to list a whole heap urls in the hosts file?

Comment: If you are using the host file then YES it's the only way. But if you have time you can alternatively install and setup any opensource local DNS server on your OSX Mountain Lion. Actually, directing domains/subdomains to their respective IPs is the job of DNS. The host file is just a local quick solution to let the machine know the right IP against the domain entry. So we are actually by passing the DNS work here using host file.

So if you really need to setup 'x.server.foo.com' to some specific IP and you want it permanently then go for installing a DNS.